# IE and strange comments behaviours : Why openning comments twice for IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I saw that strange script in the login page of https://itunesconnect.apple.com :

```
<script>
    //Some js
    <!--
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
    //--></script>
    <noscript>Some text<noscript>
```

As far as I understand, for IE it's like :

```
<script>
    //Some js
    <!--
    <!--
    //--></script>
    <noscript>Some text<noscript>
```

and for others it's like :

```
<script>
    //Some js
    <!--
    //--></script>
    <noscript>Some text<noscript>
```

But what's the purpose ? (The question is about the double "< ! - -" and not the noscript tag)
Why openning TWO times the HTML comments in a script tag on IE ?

Comment: It might be worth you reading this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/noscript

Comment: Sorry, I should have specify that the question was not about that tag. (But maybe that tag is relevant,)

Comment: @MarcB yes... it's already in the question :)

Comment: It would appear that `<!--` is also valid comment syntax. So they are just comments.

Comment: @MinusFour yes, but why TWO for IE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.write` adds its argument immediately *after* the script tag in which it was invoked, not in the tag.

In your example, putting a starting comment tag immediately after `script` tag makes all the rest of the markup on the page invisible to a browser passing the `if` condition. I.e. the rest of the page is treated as a comment. The produced code looks like this:

```
<script>
    //Some js
    <!--
    if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE')>=0)document.write(unescape('%3C')+'\!-'+'-')
    //-->
</script>
<!--<noscript>Some text<noscript>
<p>All the markup in this page will be a part of the comment in IE, if JS is enabled.</p>
```

On the page you've found this, the only purpose seems to be to hide the `noscript` tag after the script. However, it will effectively hide all the elements appended to `body` after `noscript` with JS, after the page has been parsed.

Comment: Yes ! And it's probably linked to that bug in IE8 (styled noscript has side-effects even if javascript is enabled): http://mottr.am/2009/11/30/ie8-noscript-bug-fix/ (I let you update your answer before I validate it)

Comment: If I remember correctly it was on the end of the page, so it only disabled the noscript if javascript is switched on. And if javascript is switched off, javascript is NOT executed ;) So it doen't hide the noscript element

Comment: @Tom I took a quick look at the markup on the Apple page. The tag really seems to hide `noscript` only (and ending `body` and `html` as well, creating basically invalid HTML). Looks like it really is on that page only for the IE8 bug, an awful hack though. There seems to be other things wrong for IE too, ex. a style tag defining DTD before the X-UA meta. See also my comment to Andrew's answer (sorry for the typos there).

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to open a comment twice. (The second opening tag is actually considered part of the body of the comment.) According to the Microsoft Developer Network and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx) they provide, standard HTML comments are of the style:

```
<!--
Insert HTML comment here.
-->
```

Conditional comments are also supported with the use of brackets in the following style:

```
<!--[if expression]>
HTML
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<![if expression]>
HTML
<![endif]>
```

**Update**

Back when client side scripting was new to browsers, the older browsers might not have supported the script being used. If the browser failed to recognize the script, the script would have been printed as text instead, so a workaround was necessary to prevent the old browsers from printing scripts as text on the webpage. The comment, at the bottom of the page, from the link you provided, is an example of one of these workarounds to prevent the script from being printed.

```
<!--
    script here
//-->
```

If the script is supported by the browser, then `<!--` will be interpreted as a single-line comment, and `//-->` will also be a single-line comment, because the `//` starts a single-line comment in the script. Otherwise, if the script is unsupported by the browser, then `//` would not be interpreted as a comment within the script (the browser would think it's just plain text) so `<!--`...//`-->` would be read as a multi-line comment. That way, if the browser supported the script, it would be read as a script, otherwise, it would just be commented out.

Comment: Yes. But someone took the time to write that specific js for IE and it bother me : why ??? (full disclosure : I saw it on an Apple website)

Comment: Could you provide a link to the page where you saw it?

Comment: Pure `-->` in JavaScript is syntax error. `<!--` creates a single line comment, just like `//` does. The combination of `<!-- \ncode //-->` ('\n representing an ablique new-line) is used with some (old) editors, which are capable to color HTML markup, but not JS. The single llne comment hides `-->` from JS parser, but not from editors color parser, and HTML parser, if JS isn't supported/is switched off.